# Getting running time for an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I am using the PHP AWS SDK for getting all the running instances in my account. I used the following API:

```
$this->ec2Client = Ec2Client::factory(array(
            'profile' => AWS_PROFILE, //contains my credentials
            'region' => 'ap-northeast-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
        ));

$result = $this->ec2Client->DescribeInstances(array(
            'Filters' => array(
                array('Name' => 'instance-state-name', 'Values' => array('running')),
            )
        ));
```

I can get all the running instances with the `LaunchTime`and the `AvailabilityZone` information.

The values for them are `2014-10-31T10:58:35+00:00` and `ap-northeast-1a` respectively.

Based on this information, I want to  calculate the running time in minutes. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following in v3:

```
function interval_in_minutes($start_time){
        return round(abs($start_time->getTimestamp() -
            (new \DateTime)->getTimestamp()) / 60);
    }

$running_time = interval_in_minutes($instance["LaunchTime"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value provided for each instance's `LaunchTime` should be an instance of [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). You can get how long an instance has been running by getting the difference between `LaunchTime` and another DateTime instance:

```
$interval = $launchTime->diff(new \DateTime('now'), true);
```

Comment: Since the EC2 client and other instances could be running in different AZs, do we need to consider the timezone?

Comment: No. `DateTime` objects take timezone into account when calculating a diff, and the value returned from EC2's API is an integer (epoch) timestamp.

Comment: ok, but the vaue returned for `launchTime` is `string` and I need the result in minutes. So I tried the following:
`$launch_time = new DateTime($instance["LaunchTime"]);`
`$launch_time->diff(new \DateTime('now'), true)`
Now `echo $launch_time` produces hours, minutes, days separately. Should I then manually convert to minutes?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were using v2. LaunchTime is a `DateTime` in v3 and a string in v2, but the string can be passed to `DateTime`'s constructor. `DateTime::diff` will return a `DateInterval` object, which can be formatted as per http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php